# Unable to navigate between pages using Link tag in React JS

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I am creating a navigation but when I click on the differents pages e.g About in local host nothing changes am still in the same page. Here is the code

```
 import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
 import Login from './Login';
 import About from './About';
 import Announce from './Announce';


 class Home extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
     <div>
    <div>
    <img src={banner} width="860"  alt=''/>
    </div>
    <Router>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/' >Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='./About.js'>About</Link></li>
        <li><Link  to={Announce}>Comments</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={Login}>Login</Link></li>
        
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    </Router>
  </div>

    
        );
    }
  }

  export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with only this changes , and see if you're ble to navigate between thos two

in app.js:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact>
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about">
      <About />
    </Route>

  </Switch>
</Router>
```

now in your file where you need to click (home.js i think):

```
<Link to="/">
    <span>Home</span>
</Link>
<Link to="/about">
    <span>About</span>
</Link>
```

Comment: Still nothing changes ... in fact the Home page content disappears. Home is the landing page

Comment: sorry missed the second link to about, i corected it

Comment: Still nothing changed ...

Comment: I changed the Link to <a href="'> , managed to navigate but no page contents

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

app.js

```
 <Router>
 <Switch>
 <Route path="/" exact>
  <Home />
</Route>
<Route path="/about">
  <About />
</Route>
<Route path="/login">
  <Login />
</Route>
<Route path="/announce">
  <Announce />
</Route>
</Switch>
```

Home.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import './About';
 import './Announce';
 import './Login';
  const Home =() => {

 return (
 <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='./About'>About</a></li>
        <li><a href='./Announce'>Comments</a></li>
        <li><a href='./Login'>Login</a></li>
        
      </ul>
      </nav>
 )
 }
```